# PHPMailer and 100K file limit for attachments?

Tags: php, iis, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a file as an email attachment, but for some reason if the file is > 100k then the email doesn't go through, even though I get the email sent message.
It may also be a limit on the attachments in IIS smtp setting, but when I unchecked the Limit session size and limit message size options, it didn't change anything. I may have to restart the server tonight...

I don't know if it's a php.ini setting, or what.

```
<?
$path_of_attached_file = "Images/marsbow_pacholka_big.jpg";

require 'include/PHPMailer_5.2.1/class.phpmailer.php';
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

    $body = $message; //"<p><b>Test</b> another test 3.</p>";

    $mail->AddReplyTo("admin@example.com","Admin");

    $mail->From     = "admin@example.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Admin";

    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
    $mail->AltBody  = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap = 80; // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
    if($attach){
        $mail->AddAttachment($path_of_attached_file);
    }

    $mail->Send();
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong because I don't use IIS but the code you provided would actually use a native MTA not SMTP. As far as I know you have to use the `IsSMTP()` method to let PHPMailer know that you intend to use SMTP.

Something like this:

```
<?
$path_of_attached_file = "Images/marsbow_pacholka_big.jpg";

require 'include/PHPMailer_5.2.1/class.phpmailer.php';
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

    $body = $message; //"<p><b>Test</b> another test 3.</p>";
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port 
    $mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password 

    $mail->AddReplyTo("admin@example.com","Admin");

    $mail->From     = "admin@example.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Admin";

    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
    $mail->AltBody  = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap = 80; // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
    if($attach){
        $mail->AddAttachment($path_of_attached_file);
    }

    $mail->Send();
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. Which is slightly weird because mail() is configured to go out through SMTP in php.ini... I wish I knew why this didn't work this way. Before I was using PHPMail I was trying to encode my own headers and it was putting the contents of the file into the body of the email, instead of as an attachment. So message size isn't the problem I don't think.

Comment: It also makes me a little nervous that the email said sent, but never showed up. I just sent myself a 13mb attachment so hopefully that means it is fixed, but I wish I knew what happened to all those tests before. there were no error log entries in php or smtp that I could find.

Comment: There are many quirks when it comes to PHP+IIS combination and this might just be one of them. Though as I already said I am not that much familiar with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not actually checking if the message was sent or not.
You need to change your code to check the return of the send method

```
if ($mail->Send())
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
else
  echo 'Sorry there was an error '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
```

This should give you the error message saying what is up if it does go wrong.

Comment: added that in. still got the "message has been sent" message. Don't know if it matters that the server is running on IIS 7

Comment: Check the logs for your mail server it sounds like php is adding the mail to the message queue but then the mail server is rejecting or dropping it. Also make sure you send it "From" a valid email address so you should get a bounce if it fails.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the log that said it failed. If I do a small file (80k for instance) then it works fine, so I know the from email isn't the problem. I found the Limit Message Size and limit message size options and unchecked both, but it didn't make a change. I may have to restart the server tonight to see if that fixes it.